# Overriding Rust installation default paths `$HOME/.cargo` and `$HOME/.rustup`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustup

In Rust, by default, files are placed in `$HOME/.cargo` and `$HOME/.rustup`. Is there any way to override these defaults?

I am trying to debug an obscure issue and I want to try changing the file locations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is explained [in the documentation](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/installation/index.html#choosing-where-to-install):

> `rustup` allows you to customise your installation by setting the environment variables `CARGO_HOME` and `RUSTUP_HOME` before running the `rustup-init` executable. As mentioned in the Environment Variables section, `RUSTUP_HOME` sets the root rustup folder, which is used for storing installed toolchains and configuration options. `CARGO_HOME` contains cache files used by cargo.

Don't forget to update the `$PATH` or you won't be able to use the binaries. Also, if you want that setup to be permanent, export those variables from your shell configuration (*e.g.* `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`):

> Note that you will need to ensure these environment variables are always set and that `CARGO_HOME/bin` is in the `$PATH` environment variable when using the toolchain.

Answer (score 12):

Before installing Rust, set the environment variables `CARGO_HOME` and `RUSTUP_HOME`, and make sure they're set when using the toolchain.

Add the below to your shell profile (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, etc.):

1. Environment variables for *cargo* and *rustup*

   ```sh
   export CARGO_HOME=/path/to/your/custom/location
   export RUSTUP_HOME=/path/to/your/custom/location
   ```
2. Install Rust using rustup - this is the [recommended method](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install)

   ```sh
   RUSTUP_HOME=$RUSTUP_HOME CARGO_HOME=$CARGO_HOME bash -c 'curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh'
   ```
3. Add Cargo's *bin* directory to $PATH:

   ```sh
   export PATH=$PATH:$CARGO_HOME/bin
   ```
4. Source Cargo's environment

   ```sh
   source "$CARGO_HOME/env"
   ```
5. Restart shell

Verify:

```sh
rustc --version
cargo --version
```

Comment: This appears to be the same as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57766821/155423), which also says you should set `CARGO_HOME` and `CARGO_HOME`. Please [edit] this answer to clarify what new information is provided.